# Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM

Tags: cleos, nodeos, keosd

I was trying to deploy my smart contract to the local testnet and got this error.

> Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM

I was using a command `cleos set contract testing . hello.wast hello.abi -p testing`

Nodeos output:

```
  Produced block 000009736bfdf868... #2419 @ 2018-08-15T10:10:19.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 0, lib: 2418, confirmed: 0]
2018-08-15T10:10:19.780 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:472           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
2018-08-15T10:10:19.780 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:473           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3070003 wasm_serialization_error: Serialization Error Processing WASM
magic number: loaded 1685024040 but was expecting 1836278016
    {}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:40 validate
pending console output:
    {"console":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:61 exec_one
```

Comment: This is a very general error. Maybe you can provide some more code and explanation.

Comment: I just used `eosiocpp -o hello.wast hello.abi ` and `eosiocpp -g hello.abi hello.cpp` and just tried to deploy it by using cleos set contract.

Comment: Ok. Did you try to change the folder path `cleos set contract testing ./ hello.wast hello.abi -p testing`? I don't know if `.` is a valid path.

Comment: Yes, I have even tried to show the full path like Users/user/documents/eos/contracts/hello

Comment: Are you using Docker or a local version? And did you change anything in the contract?

Comment: I am using local version. No, I haven't changed anything in a contract. It's not the only contract i can't deploy. Every contract I try to deploy does not work.

Comment: Is this a typo or did you really run this command: 
    eosiocpp -o hello.wast hello.abi
You should use the cpp source to create the wast file

Comment: My log from the latest attempt: 17:01 $ eosiocpp -o infinite.wast infinite.cpp 17:01 $ eosiocpp -g infinite.abi infinite.cpp 17:01 $ cleos set contract testing ~/documents/eos/contracts/infinite infinite.wast infinite.abi -p testing
Reading WASM from /Users/justin/documents/eos/contracts/infinite/infinite.wast...
Publishing contract...
Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that I was using .wast and you can no longer use .wast you have to use .wasm

Comment: @JustinZ could you please post the solution that worked for you so the question doesn't appear as unanswered and new readers can find the answer?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it. The problem was that I was using `.wast` and you can no longer use .wast you have to use `.wasm`

Comment: Cheers! Glad you solved it and answered your own question so others know how to deal with it as well.

Comment: yeah I found it useful too(brofist)